# How to get optimal strokecolor for high contrast drawing on current maptype google maps api V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, colors, google-maps-api-2

I'm migrating a complex map from V2 to V3. The user can digitize polygons and polylines. In V2 getting a high contrast strokeColor was as easy as:

`var strokeColor = GMap.getCurrentMapType().getLinkColor();`

and that was useful in a handler for the map event, *maptypechanged*.

How can I do this in V3?

Comment: I don't think there is a built in function for that in v3.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched the [API v3 reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) quite thoroughly and it seems that almost surely you can't. It's sad, but many many features are missing in API v3 without any library or replacement offered.

Comment: Thanks, and me too I searched as well. I suppose a quick and easy way to get the same functionality is to write a javascript function that references an associative array keyed to the `google.maps.MapTypeId` enumeration; picking the values to be appropriate colors.

Comment: @subsci well but the problem is where to pick these colors from.